# Server-side rendering Spring and Vue.js

Tags: java, spring, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I have Spring Boot MVC project with Vue.js. I build main.js through webpack, then main.js is connected to my template. And at the output I get one div tag in the html file. Is there a way to do server-side rendering without rewriting most of the code?

Comment: I found better solution, using SPA during development, and Prerender + Client-side-rendering during deployment. Thanks [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

For vue itself you can use this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html

It's not best practise to deploy the vue app inside the spring app.

Instead you should deploy the vue app on a webserver (e.g. nginx / apache2) and deploy the spring app separate.

Cheers!